Expectation of area of random projection
I am thinking about a solution with Mathematica of a problem from 14th Kolmogorov competition (2015) on probability

A planar polygon in three-dimensional space is projected onto a randomly chosen
plane (i.e., the unit normal to the plane is uniformly distributed on the sphere).
Find the mathematical expectation of the projection area if  the area of the polygon equals $S$.

I find in WolframMathWorld a formula that
describes a random point on the unit sphere  TransformedDistribution[{x1/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2],  x2/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2],  x3/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2]}, {x1, x2, x3} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[IdentityMatrix[3]]] and stuck here.

@Downvoter: What is incorrect in my question?

In the original answer by hand which I don't understand much  the integral $$\frac 2 {4\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\ \sin(\varphi)\cos(\varphi),d\varphi d\theta $$ is calculated.

Boys who voted to close the question: "This question doesn’t meet a Mathematica Stack Exchange guideline". What does not meet this gideline?

(-1) Almost all of your so-called problems are used to provoke fights instead of discussions.

numerical experiment:
Abs[Normalize[#][[3]]] & /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10^6, 3}] // Mean
(*    0.500006    *)

exact by using spherical coordinates: the projected area is $S\cdot\left|\cos\theta\right|$ and the average is $\langle\left|\cos\theta\right|\rangle=\frac12$:
Integrate[Abs[Cos[θ]] Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}] / Integrate[Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}]
(*    1/2    *)


Solved ($1/2$):  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltLUadnCyi0

@DavidG.Stork: You are not right. A similar problem (the average of the random shadow of the cube) is solved on YouTube. The same questions arise: (i) "Why is the projected area equal to S⋅|cosθ| "? (ii)  What is the sample space?  Thank you anyway.

Thank you. You mimic the answer done by hand which is too short. There are some moments I don't understand: (i) Can you elaborate your "the projected area is S⋅|cosθ| "? (ii) How do you calculate the average? What is the sample space? TIA.

""Why is the projected area equal to S⋅|cosθ| "? (ii) What is the sample space? Thank you anyway."  see 7:30 in youtube.com/watch?v=ltLUadnCyi0

@DavidG.Stork: Thank you. I see plausible reasoning. I see neither math nor Mathematica there. I don't see the sample space (the unit sphere) at all.

The sample space is $\theta$, as the video and Roman state ever so clearly.

The area of the shadow/projection is $\cos\theta$ because it's the only spherical harmonic that makes sense. Think of it in terms of the Lie group of 3D rotations and what has to happen to the projection as you rotate the plane. Then, consider only the magnitude $\left|\cos\theta\right|$ because we don't care about the sign of the shadow projection. But there's not enough space here for an elementary introduction to 3D geometry.

@Roman: Sorry, I am waiting for a serious reply.

You already know what you want and expect someone to deliver exactly what you want? That's not going to work in life. You need to show effort in trying to understand what others offer.

@Roman Please see my answer to the question.

To long to be a comment under Roman's answer: the numerical experiment can be carried out by RandomPoint to get faster random point generating in unit sphere, just like RandomPoint[Sphere[], 10^6].
RandomPoint[Sphere[], 10^6][[All, 3]] // Abs // Mean // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.066198, 0.500014}*)

Abs[Normalize[#][[3]]] & /@ 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10^6, 3}] // 
  Mean // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.66592, 0.50007}*)

Ten-times faster in my machine.

This is a comment, not an answer, and could be presented as a comment.

Not too long for a comment.T o long to be a comment under Roman's answer: the numerical experiment can be carried out by RandomPoint to get faster random point generating in unit sphere, just like RandomPoint[Sphere[], 10^6].
RandomPoint[Sphere[], 10^6][[All, 3]] // Abs // Mean // AbsoluteTiming`
({0.066198, 0.500014})
Abs[Normalize[#][[3]]] & /@     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10^6, 3}] //    Mean // AbsoluteTiming
({0.66592, 0.50007})

On the same web Sphere Point Picking as in OP there is also formula for random point on a sphere in spherical coordinates (with error of swapping $\theta$ and $\phi$ which I corrected).
Then it is really simple if we use the fact stated in answer by @Roman that projected area is equal to $S\cdot\left|\cos\theta\right|$.
{r, theta, phi} = {1, ArcCos[2 v - 1], 2 Pi u};

Expectation[
 Abs[Cos[theta]], {u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[], 
  v \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[]}]

(*simplified version*)
Expectation[Abs[2 v - 1], v \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[]]

Clear[r, theta, phi]


1/2

1/2


Thank you for your work. Can you give a solid accessible reference to "the fact stated in answer by @Roman that projected area is equal to $S|\cos(\theta)|$"? What is denoted by $\theta$? What is/are the sample space/spaces in your calculations? Did you pay your attention to  my comment to my question with the formula from the original answer?

@user64494 Theta is angle between positive z axis and normal vector to the surface of polygon being projected to xy plane.

Thank you. I repeat my requests about the reference and sample spaces.

Here is my answer to my question. First, the formula $S*|\cos(\theta)|$ is derived with Mathematica. Without loss of the generality, we may assume that a planar polygon is a triangle Triangle[{{x1, y1, 0}, {x2, y2, 0}, {x3, y3, 0}}]in the plane $xOy$ with
 Area[Triangle[{{x1, y1, 0}, {x2, y2, 0}, {x3, y3, 0}}]]


1/2 Sqrt[(-x2 y1 + x3 y1 + x1 y2 - x3 y2 - x1 y3 + x2 y3)^2]

Now we consider the plane in the three-dimensional space with normal {Cos[\[Alpha]], Cos[\[Beta]], Cos[\[Theta]]} passing through the origin
h = Hyperplane[{Cos[\[Alpha]], Cos[\[Beta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}, 0];

and find the projections of the vertices of the triangle onto this plane. For example,
RegionNearest[h, {x1, y1, 0}]


{x1 - (Cos[\[Alpha]] (x1 Cos[\[Alpha]] + y1 Cos[\[Beta]]))/( Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 + Cos[\[Beta]]^2 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2),  y1 - (Cos[\[Beta]] (x1 Cos[\[Alpha]] + y1 Cos[\[Beta]]))/( Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 + Cos[\[Beta]]^2 +  Cos[\[Theta]]^2), -(((x1 Cos[\[Alpha]] +  y1 Cos[\[Beta]]) Cos[\[Theta]])/( Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 + Cos[\[Beta]]^2 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2))}

At last,
FullSimplify[Area[Triangle[{RegionNearest[h, {x1, y1, 0}], 
RegionNearest[h, {x2, y2, 0}], RegionNearest[h, {x3, y3, 0}]}]]/
Area[Triangle[{{x1, y1, 0}, {x2, y2, 0}, {x3, y3, 0}}]], 
Assumptions ->  Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 + Cos[\[Beta]]^2 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2 == 1 && \[Theta] \[Element] Reals]


Abs[Cos[\[Theta]]]

finishes the work.
Now we realize the approach with normal distributions
ToSphericalCoordinates[{x1/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2], 
x2/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2],  x3/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2]}] // Simplify


{1, ArcTan[x3/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2], Sqrt[(x1^2 + x2^2)/( x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2)]],  ArcTan[x1/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2], x2/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2]]}

FullSimplify[Cos[ArcTan[x3/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2], 
Sqrt[(x1^2 + x2^2)/(x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2)]]]]


x3/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2]

z = TransformedDistribution[ x3/Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2], 
{x1, x2, x3} \[Distributed] MultinormalDistribution[IdentityMatrix[3]]]


UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}]

The last step is
Mean[TransformedDistribution[RealAbs[z], 
z \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}]]]


1/2


What is incorrect in my answer? It is unfair to down vote without any explanatory comment.

(-1)_Please elaboard that may assume that a planar polygon is a triangle
